# Umbraco CMS - Update content on several environments

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco

I have problem in finding the best solution for synchronizing content between several Umbraco (**Verison: 4.7.2**) instances. 
So the situation is: I have three environments (dev, pre-production, production) with their own separate databases and Umbraco installed on them. Currently if I updating content on my dev instance I need to repeat this procedure on other two.  Content can be updated on all of these environments. So I need to have some tool which will synchronize content on all others environments, immediately after it was updated.
I found couple of out-of-box solutions such as [Umbraco Courier](http://umbraco.com/products/more-add-ons/courier-2.aspx) and [uSync](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync). 
I have problems with both of them. 
The first one is commercial; the second is working only with Umbraco version 4.10.x. I can’t pay for this, and at the same time it’s rather hard for me to upgrade Umbraco on all of these environments. Currently I need to upgrade only content. 
I’m kind of wary of developing something which will work directly with databases, but that’s the only solution I can see now. 
So can you please advise me something on this?

Answer (score 1):

uSync is open source, so it's possible that you could fork it and make a version that would work with older versions of Umbraco? There is a forum post [here](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/developer-tools/usync/usync/40926-Umbraco-491) that implies that it can be done reasonably easily.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but we decided to implement this on database layer, using replication

Comment: @user2099703 could you please describe more detailed your solution?

Comment: What we were planning to implement is to use built in data-replication in SQL Server, and schedule the replication of Umbraco database once a week. We were planning to propagate data from production server to our pre-production and dev environments. Also we disabled the Umbraco content cache to force Umbraco pick all the changes immediately.